# How to verify from "uname -a" output, the installed Solaris OS is openSolaris or not

Tags: solaris

How to verify from `uname -a` output, if the installed Solaris OS is openSolaris or not.

I need to know the type of OS installed like, Solaris or opensolaris or Solaris Express etc

```
cat /etc/release
Solaris 10 3/05 s10_74L2a SPARC
Copyright 2005 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Use is subject to license terms.
Assembled 22 January 2005

uname -a
SunOS sndcc02.sanjose.ibm.com 5.10 Generic sun4u sparc
SUNW,Sun-Fire-V490
```

Answer (score 6):

The OpenSolaris distro identified itself in /etc/release, as did Solaris Express - neither has existed or been supported in years though, so checking for them is not really relevant today.   Also, only a development version of SunOS 5.11 was ever released as OpenSolaris - if uname reports SunOS 5.10, it is the Solaris 10 release that predates OpenSolaris.

As an example, OpenSolaris 2009.06 had this in /etc/release:

```
                     OpenSolaris 2009.06 snv_111b X86
       Copyright 2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
                    Use is subject to license terms.
                          Assembled 07 May 2009
```

And Solaris 11 Express 2010.11 had this in /etc/release:

```
                  Oracle Solaris 11 Express snv_151a X86
 Copyright (c) 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
                       Assembled 04 November 2010
```

Comment: Just in case you want to check the release details on Solaris 11, you can run 'pkg info entire' command to get the exact version and build details.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/commands-find-out-solaris-os-version-ralus-rmal-issues), I see you could also issue `showrev` command to find out the version.

```
$ showrev –a
Hostname: starbug
Hostid: nnnnnnnn
Release: 5.9
Kernel architecture: sun4u
Application architecture: sparc
Hardware provider: Sun_Microsystems
Domain: solar.com
Kernel version: SunOS 5.9 May 2002
```

Comment: `showrev` was removed in OpenSolaris and Solaris 11 & later, so can only give answers for Solaris 10 & older.